# Database schema design for employee leave system

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

**Scenario:**

An employee accumulates ***n*** number of days per month from the date they were engaged. Different employee categories are entitled to different number of days per month, say a Senior staff may be entitled to 2.5 days while a junior staff might be entitled to 2.0 days & an intern 1.75 days.

When an employee is promoted say from junior to senior their monthly leave entitlement should change as well but their accumulated leave total should account for that change in category. i.e if a junior staff worked for two months(**2.0 / month**) and on the third month is promoted to senior staff (**rate now changes to 2.5 / month**), what would be the best way to compute their accumulated leave total?

If the rate was uniform across the board, i wouldn't have any problem computing the days accumulated when employee category changes. Here an employees category can change from one to another at any time during their course of employment.

How would be the best schema design for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have your employee table

```
+--------------+
|   employee   |
+==============+
| employee_id  |
+--------------+
| more rows... |
+--------------+
```

Then you may have a separate table to track seniority level changes with start and end dates, whereby end_date = null means the employee is currently in that seniority level.

```
+--------------+
| level_events |
+==============+
| event_id     |
+--------------+
| employee_id  |
+--------------+
| level_id     |
+--------------+
| start_date   |
+--------------+
| end_date     |
+--------------+
```

You need a table to correlate seniority level with leave rates.

```
+-------------+
| level_rates |
+=============+
| level_id    |
+-------------+
| rate        |
+-------------+
```

From here, there are a million different ways you could go, and it depends on your programming language and style.

Basically, you need something like the following pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM level_events INNER JOIN level_rates ON level_id
WHERE employee_id = <the employee in question>

var months = 0
var leave = 0
var month_interval = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  // days * hours * minutes * seconds

for Row in Results
  if (end_date == null)
    end_date = NOW()
  date_diff = end_date - start_date
  months = date_diff / month_interval
  leave += months * rate

return leave
```

Of course, you would also want a table like "leave_used" to track used leave and subtract it from the leave accrued.

Hope this helps get some ideas rolling!